# Stream filter add condition

Tags: java, stream

How can I add a condition only when `result.getExtendedAddress()` exists using Lamdas?

Original condition:

```
.filter(result -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(title) && StringUtils.contains(result.getTitle().toLowerCase(), title.toLowerCase()))
```

New condition:

```
.filter(result -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(title) &&
                        (StringUtils.contains(result.getTitle().toLowerCase(), title.toLowerCase()) ||
                                ((result.getExtendedAddress()!= null) && (StringUtils.contains(result.getExtendedAddress().toLowerCase(), title.toLowerCase()))))
```

This new condition seems overly complicated and I would like to know if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Not giving this as an answer because I don't know `StringUtils` enough to be sure how it handles `null` inputs, but I think `Optional.ofNullable(result.getExtendedAddress()).map(String::toLowerCase).orElse(null)` should work.

Comment: Assuming you're using Apache Common's `StringUtils` you could also use `StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase()` to get rid of the null checks: `filter(StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(result.getTitle(), title) || StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(result.getExtendedAddress(), title))`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. Yes I am using org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Thomas I was able to quickly find the solution using `StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase()`. The method is described [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-).

Solution:

```
.filter(result -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(title) &&
                        (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(result.getTitle(), title) ||
                                StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(result.getAdditionalAddress(), title)))
```